# Django filter ORM Q

Tags: python, mysql, django, filter, orm

I'm writing this query:

```
day_l = DAYLeave.objects.filter(user=request.user,  Q(start_date__range=[sd, ed]) | Q(end_date__range=[sd, ed]))
```

`sd` and `ed` are Dates like '2021-04-06'

when I execute I get this error:

```
SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument
```

user --> foreign key to User table

If I remove `user=request.user` it works but in my main query I get the error.

Comment: Put `user=request.user` at the end. Keyword args should come after non-keyword args.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put `user=request.user` at the end. Keyword args should come after non-keyword args.

```
day_l = DAYLeave.objects.filter(
    Q(start_date__range=[sd, ed]) | Q(end_date__range=[sd, ed]), 
    user=request.user,
)
```